Is the "power set function" a function?
The notation usually used to denote the power set of a set $A$ is basically the same as that used to denote a function having $A$ as its argument: $\mathcal P(A)$. However, is it actually a function? Its domain would be the set of all sets, which does not exist in ZF. However, it really does behave like a function.
So, is the "power set function" a function?

It’s a class function. (Like the 4th paragraph down.)

There is a "Power Set Clas Function", ( it is even an injection from V into the set of all Powersets) which does behave like a function- however it only exists in the meta-theory. Within Set Theory, P(x) denotes the unique set which is the set of all subsets of x, it is just a piece of Notation.
